# Sequelize Bulk Update Array Issue

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have a list of records that I'm looking to bulk update with the adjusted values in the individual form fields. When I try to run a POST and update the records based on the values in the inputs, I run into an error at the Where clause and I'm wondering how I can parse my `discoverySourceId` value for the where clause or what would be the best method to use with my current setup.

```
Error: Missing where attribute in the options parameter passed to update.
```

**Route:**

```
var appRoutes   = express.Router();
var _ = require('lodash-node');
var async = require('async');
var models = require('../models/db-index');

    appRoutes.route('app/settings/discovery-sources')

    .get(function(req, res){
        models.DiscoverySource.findAll({
                where: {
                    organizationId: req.user.organizationId
                }, attributes: ['discoverySourceId', 'discoverySourceName']
            }).then(function(discoverySource){
            res.render('pages/app/settings-discovery-sources.hbs', {
                discoverySource: discoverySource
            });
        })
    })
        .post(function(req, res){
                console.log('POST Triggered');
                var sources = _.map(req.body.discoverySourceName, function (source) {
                    return {
                         discoverySourceName: source,
                         discoverySourceId: req.body.discoverySourceId
                    };
                });
                models.DiscoverySource.update(sources).then(function(){
                    console.log("Successful update");
                    res.redirect('/settings/discovery-sources');
                });
            });

**Form:**

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="annotation-form">
                <h2>Discovery Sources</h2>
                <form action="/app/settings/discovery-sources" method="post">
                {{#each discoverySource}}
                    <input type="hidden" name="discoverySourceId" value={{this.discoverySourceId}}>
                    <input type="text" name="discoverySourceName[0]" value="{{this.discoverySourceName}}"><a href="#" id="settings-delete-discovery-source">Delete</a>
                    <br />
                {{else}}
                    <p>No Discovery Sources</p>
                {{/each}}
                    <button type="submit">Update Sources</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**discoverySource:**

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var DiscoverySource = sequelize.define('discovery_source', {
    discoverySourceId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'discovery_source_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        notNull: true,
    },
    discoverySourceName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'discovery_source_name'
    },
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT,
        field: 'organization_id'
    },
},{
    freezeTableName: true
});
    return DiscoverySource;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the where clause in the update call. Pass the organizationId into the where clause, otherwise it would update every single row in the DiscoverySource table.

Comment: How should I include the where clause? I tried `models.DiscoverySource.update(sources, { where: { discoverySourceId: req.body.discoverySourceId}})`, but receive a `Unhandled rejection TypeError: build.set is not a function` error

Comment: I'm guessing here, but req.body.discoverySourceId is most likely a string  type not a Number type(Because hidden inputs are parsed as strings, not numbers). Try parseInt(req.body.discoverySourceId)

Comment: Thanks for the insight on the value for the hidden input passing a string. I made the adjustment, but still receive the `Unhandled rejection TypeError: build.set is not a function`. Any thoughts on what I should try next?

Comment: I have figured out the error but I'm trying to figure out how it's best for you to solve it. One question, is there any special reason that discoverySourceName is an array in your html? Aren't you simply updating a single discoverySource? Not a lot of them at once?

Comment: This form would be updating all records. In my view file there is a for-loop that sets inputs for each field and clicking on the update would bulk update them. Is this the big issue causing the error? Thanks for looking into this deeper

Comment: The problem is that you are passing an array to the update function, which doesnt accept an array. I can type out a full answer tomorrow(its 2am here) but until then this will have to do.

Comment: That would be great. Thank you for going above and beyond with this question

Comment: @GrimurD were you able to come up with an answer? no worries if you haven't had the time

Comment: I'm sorry I totally forgot. One thing, can you show me how this discoverysource model looks like. The form looks pretty odd to me so I can't be sure what it looks like.

Comment: No worries! I updated my question to include the model. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @GrimurD I also updated the question to include the modules being used just in case you were confused by what the variables represented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var appRoutes = express.Router();
var _ = require('lodash-node'); // just use lodash, using lodash-node is deprecated and it's redundant.
var async = require('async');
var models = require('../models/db-index');

// Added these for context
var app = express();
var Promise = require('bluebird'); // or Q if you prefer.

// Make sure you're using body-parser urlencoded
// with extended set to true. This allows us to have
// fancy body parsing for forms.
// This line must be above all your routes.
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}))

appRoutes.route('app/settings/discovery-sources')
    .get(function (req, res) {
        models
            .DiscoverySource
            .findAll({
                where: {
                    organizationId: req.user.organizationId
                },
                attributes: ['discoverySourceId', 'discoverySourceName']
            })
            .then(function (discoverySource) {
                res.render('pages/app/settings-discovery-sources.hbs', {
                    discoverySource: discoverySource
                });
            })
    })
    .post(function (req, res) {
        console.log('POST Triggered');
        // We use promise.map to map the array in the body into an array of promises
        // which are resolved when each promise has been resolved. 
        // It's a good idea here to use sequelize.transaction() so that if one update
        // fails, everything gets rolled back.
        // If you're using Q it doesn't support .map() so this looks slightly different in that case. 
        // q.all(_.map(req.body.discoverySources, function() {}))
        Promise
            .map(req.body.discoverySources, function (source) {
                return models
                    .DiscoverySource
                    .update({
                        discoverySourceName: source.name
                    }, {
                        // We have to call update with the ID of each discoverySource so that
                        // we update the names of each discovery source correctly.
                        where: {
                            discoverySourceId: source.id
                        }
                    })
            })
            .then(function () {
                console.log("Successful update");
                res.redirect('/settings/discovery-sources');
            });
    });
```

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
        <div class="annotation-form">
            <h2>Discovery Sources</h2>
            <form action="/app/settings/discovery-sources" method="post">
                {{#each discoverySource}}
                <!-- Use body parser urlencoded syntax so the request body is parsed into an array of objects with the
                 properties id and name. See the qs library for syntax documentation, https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs#readme -->
                <input type="hidden" name="discoverySources[][id]" value={{this.discoverySourceId}}>
                <input type="text" name="discoverySources[][name]" value="{{this.discoverySourceName}}"><a href="#" id="settings-delete-discovery-source">Delete</a>
                <br /> {{else}}
                <p>No Discovery Sources</p>
                {{/each}}
                <button type="submit">Update Sources</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and it is definitely the best approach, but I run into an error: `Unhandled rejection SequelizeValidationError: string violation: discoverySourceName cannot be an array or an object`. Any thoughts on this error? Is this basically indicating that I need to loop through the `.update()` method on the route side instead of passing the elements to an array in the view?

Comment: No theres probably an error in the html i wrote. Do a console.log on req.body in the post route and check wherher it has an array of objects with the two properties set correctly. Sounds like discoverysourcename is an array for some reason.

Comment: What template engine are you using? Mustache?

Comment: Handlebars is the template engine I'm using

Comment: Then that part at least looks right, have you tried logging the contents of the body to the console?

Comment: When I log `req.body.discoverySources` I get the arrays within arrays. ``[ { id: [ '1', '2', '3' ],
    name: [ 'Test 1', 'Test 2', 'Test 3' ] } ]``

Comment: What does the html look like when you are on the page? And are you definitely using bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true }); ?

Comment: I will be able to provide that to you a little later today. Yes, in my app.js file I have `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));`

Comment: the source code looks like this `<input type="hidden" name="discoverySources[][id]" value=1>
        <input type="text" name="discoverySources[][name]" value="Test 1"><a href="#" id="settings-delete-discovery-source">Delete</a>
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="discoverySources[][id]" value=2>
        <input type="text" name="discoverySources[][name]" value="Test 2"><a href="#" id="settings-delete-discovery-source">Delete</a>`

Comment: And the Form Data looks like this: `discoverySources[][id]:1
discoverySources[][name]:Test 1
discoverySources[][id]:2
discoverySources[][name]:Test 2`

Comment: I just created a small test app and the body was parsed correctly. You must be doing something wrong. I used the HTML that you pasted. See http://pastebin.com/5q327GPU

Comment: I fixed the error by changing source.name to string: `source.name.toString()`, but the result is that all of my records are updated with the array values for each record. http://imgbox.com/OFEp3SRp

Comment: Small tweak and it started to work. Thank you so much @GrimurD !

Answer (score 0):

Just to add on @GrimurD answer - if when updating you want to get back the updated data you can do:

```
  Promise
    .all(_.map(clients, (client) => {
      const { firstName, lastName, phoneNumber, emailAddress } = client;
      return Client
        .update({
          firstName,
          lastName,
          phoneNumber,
          emailAddress,
        }, {
          where: {
            id: client.id,
          },
          returning: true,
          plain: true,
        });
    }))
    .then((results) => {
      // do whatever you want with the returned results
      const updatedClients = results.map(result => _.omit(result[1].dataValues, ['salt', 'password']));
      callback(null, updatedClients);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      callback({ error: true, message: err.message ? err.message : 'Unable to fetch updated user details' });
    });
```

So all the updated records will be returned as an array of objects and the you can do whatever you want with that data.